# Android: Previous Activity is not finished in using FLAG ACTIVITY CLEAR TOP

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm new to Android programming so I might miss something important.

What I want to do is to finish the current activity (ActivityB) and the previous activity (ActivityA).
And the users can switch between ActivityA and ActivityB using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. Now I want to finish `ActivityB` and the previous `ActivityA` and start new `ActivityA`.

However, seems like the previous `ActivityA` is still running even after finishing `ActivityB`.

Code is like this.

`ActivityA`

```
private void startActivityB() {
          Intent intent =
                    new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

`ActivityB`

```
private void exitActivityB() {
                       Intent intent =
                        new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
private void onBackPressed() {
        // finish ActivityB and the previous ActivityA
        Intent intent =
                new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

What am I wrong with this? How can I finish the previous `ActivityA` and start new `ActivityA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@Override
private void onBackPressed() {
        // finish ActivityB and the previous ActivityA
        Intent intent =
                new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class); 
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i); 
finish();
```